# Listeners in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript.

Here is what I need to be able to do (preferably without JQuery or any other external library).

When a certain event happens, I want to notify the user via a callback. I am wondering how I should go about doing this.

I have a class that I am working on (a function of functions)

and ideally I would like the user to be able to set callbacks something like this:

```
function myOnTouch(front,back) {
//do stuff
}

apiInstance.onTouch = myOnTouch;
```

I am not sure if this is how JavaScript works, but if someone could point me in the right direction on creating callbacks for JavaScript classes, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this could work. You then just would trigger this listener by `apiInstance.onTouch(…)`

Comment: The disadvantage of `apiInstance.onTouch = myOnTouch` is that you can only register a single listener. This can be limiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your class wants to notify the user, it simply calls the callback:

```
if (this.onTouch) {
    this.onTouch(this.front, this.back);
}
```

You could also have multiple callbacks, and do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.onTouch.length; i++) {
    this.onTouch[i](this.fron, this.back);
}
```

You can then provide an API to add listeners:

```
apiInstance.addOnTouch(myOnTouch);
```

The implementation would look like:

```
function addOnTouch(callback) {
    this.onTouch.push(callback);
}
```